# Como crear graficas con Javascript de una matiz?

Tags: javascript

Que tal gente estoy buscando un plugin o herramienta que me ayude a crear unas graficas el problema de los que he visto son las normales de lineas o barras y necesito hacer algo como matriz como se muestra a continuacion en la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/), es gratis, aunque si quieres que desaparezca la leyenda de [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/) de tus gráficos ahí si tendrás que pagar. Esta muy bien documentada.